# R: rgl link multiple plots to a single widget

Tags: r, rgl

I'm trying to link a `playwidget()` slider to multiple plot so that the slider affects all plots. I want to use it in a Rmarkdown file and not in a Shiny application.

I managed to append the plots in the `subsetControl` and added the `subscenes` control, but it's not working properly: the first subset works fine but if I move the slider I get the first plot (with black and red points) duplicated in both plots.

```
library(rgl)

open3d() # Remove the earlier display

layout3d(matrix(c(1,2), nrow=1), sharedMouse = T)

next3d()
setosa <- with(subset(iris, Species == "setosa"), 
               spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                         col="black",
                         radius = 0.211))
versicolor <- with(subset(iris, Species == "versicolor"), 
                   spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                             col="red",
                             radius = 0.211))

next3d()
setosa2 <- with(subset(iris, Species == "setosa"), 
                spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                          col="yellow",
                          radius = 0.211))
versicolor2 <- with(subset(iris, Species == "versicolor"), 
                    spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                              col="blue",
                              radius = 0.211))


rglwidget() %>%
  playwidget(start = 0, stop = 2, interval = 1,
             subsetControl(1, subscenes = subsceneList(), subsets = list(
               All = c(setosa, setosa2, versicolor, versicolor2),
               Setosa = c(setosa, setosa2),
               Versicolor = c(versicolor, versicolor2)
             )))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model used in `rgl` subscenes is that the root owns all the objects, and each subscene displays some of them.  Your code starts by displaying `setosa` and `versicolor` in the first subscene and `setosa2` and `versicolor2` in the second one, but the the subset control says to display *both* `setosa` and `setosa2` in one subset, and *both* `versicolor` and `versicolor2` in the other, and do this in *both* subscenes.  Since `setosa` and `setosa2` have the same shape and location, only one appears at a time: the first drawn.

To get what you want, you need two `subsetControl`s, both controlled by the same `playwidget`, e.g.

```
library(rgl)

open3d() # Remove the earlier display

layout3d(matrix(c(1,2), nrow=1), sharedMouse = T)

next3d()
sub1 <- subsceneInfo()$id
setosa <- with(subset(iris, Species == "setosa"), 
                             spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                                                col="black",
                                                radius = 0.211))
versicolor <- with(subset(iris, Species == "versicolor"), 
                                     spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                                                        col="red",
                                                        radius = 0.211))

next3d()
sub2 <- subsceneInfo()$id
setosa2 <- with(subset(iris, Species == "setosa"), 
                                spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                                                    col="yellow",
                                                    radius = 0.211))
versicolor2 <- with(subset(iris, Species == "versicolor"), 
                                        spheres3d(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, 
                                                            col="blue",
                                                            radius = 0.211))


rglwidget() %>%
    playwidget(start = 0, stop = 2, interval = 1,
                         list(subsetControl(1, subscenes = sub1, subsets = list(
                            All = c(setosa, versicolor),
                            Setosa = setosa,
                            Versicolor = versicolor
                         )),
                         subsetControl(1, subscenes = sub2, subsets = list(
                            All = c(setosa2, versicolor2),
                            Setosa = setosa2,
                            Versicolor = versicolor2
                         ))))
```